# Create a deletebutton that deletes from datagridview and updates sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Okey so im kinda new at development. Im in school and we just got a project on *C#*. The thing is that we have to do everything using *MVC*. Anyway, i need to create a button that when i get the messagebox and press Yes it will delete the row/s i've selected in my datagridview and at the same time it should update my Database. Ive created a *DAL* and a Controller for this. Now im having difficulties to create a try/catch/exception for my button in my button event.

Im posting the code for the delete action in both controller and my dal. Ive been googling about it for so long yesterday but cant manage to implement others idea in mine.

P.S. The reason for me using bool is that i saw a tutorial that used it, maybe i should use something else better fitting for my project?

DAL

```
public bool DeleteMembers()
{                
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = 
       new SqlCommand("delete from member where SocialSecurity=@SocialSecurity", 
           con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return true;
}
```

**TController**

```
public bool DeleteMembers()
{
    bool cmd = dal.DeleteMembers();
    return cmd;
}
```

**Eventhandler**

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try... 
}
```

Ive also managed to do a foreach method that deletes rows in my datagridview.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dtGrid1.SelectedRows)
{
    dtGrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

P.S. im not using parameters. So no code with parameters, im not educated enough to do so and we dont have to in our project. I know about sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The GridView component is not intended to be used in ASP.NET MVC applications. This component relies heavily on ViewState and PostBack which are notions that no longer exist in ASP.NET MVC.

You could use the [`WebGrid helper`](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/01/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid.aspx) in order to show the records in your view and provide a Delete functionality.

So the first step is to design a model which will represent the records you want to be displayed on your view:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SocialSecurity { get; set; }
}
```

Then next step is to have a data layer which will query your relational database and pull out the model. You could use an ORM such as Entity Framework to simplify this task or directly use plain ADO.NET which is what I will illustrate here:

```
public class PeopleRepository
{
    public IList<Person> Get()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionString["SomeConnectionStringKey"]
            .ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, fname, lname, ssn FROM people";
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var result = new List<Person>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(new Person
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrindal("id")),
                        FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrindal("fname")),
                        LastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrindal("lname")),
                        SocialSecurity = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrindal("ssn"))
                    });
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionString["SomeConnectionStringKey"]
            .ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The next step is to have a controller which will do the wiring between your Model and the View:

```
public class PeopleController: Controller
{
    private readonly PeopleRepository repo = new PeopleRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Person> model = repo.Get();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        repo.Delete(id);
        IList<Person> model = repo.Get();
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

and the final step of course will be the view:

```
@model IList<Person>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(columnName: "Id"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First name"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last name"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "SocialSecurity", header: "Social Security Number"),
        grid.Column(
            header: "", 
            format: 
                @<text>
                    <form action="@Url.Action("Delete", "People", new { id = item.Id })" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this person?');">
                        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </text>
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Forgot to write that im not using asp. Dont know why asp.net-mvc is in the tags.

Comment: Yes, I know that you are not using ASP. You have mentioned in your question that you are using ASP.NET MVC. I have updated my answer to provide you a little more guidance.

Comment: I know it sounds weird but our teacher is a bit weird. He wants us to have MVC on a Windows form project. This is why its so difficult to do this.